# Pivot table data in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

i have data like this

```
id      Amount      coluName    
13        25000         abccol  
13        2300          defcol
```

but i want data like this

```
id        abccol   defcol
13      25000     2300
```

query

```
select e.id,e.Amount,i.ColuName
 from FixAm  e
inner join InCo i on i.CCode=e.CCode
where cid=49
```

how to do this through pivot ?in this there is not only two names (abccol,defcol) there is also many other but i used here only these two

Comment: What's the expected result if the row (13, 1000, 'ghicol') suddenly shows up in your table?

Comment: same result but with addition of ghicol column and the amount 1000.. like this id abccol defcol ghicol .... 13 0 0 1000

Comment: Tag the dbms you're using. (The answer will perhaps use some product specific functionality.)

Comment: i did.. which is sql

Comment: SQL is a language specified by ISO/ANSI. There are many different products implementing SQL, more or less standard compliant. When it comes to pivot, the query will most probably be product specific.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might work for you.
User **@jarlh** is right when saying in the comments that you need to specify the version of SQL Server you are using, though.

```
declare @cols as nvarchar(max)
     ,  @query  as nvarchar(max)

select @cols = stuff((select distinct ',' + quotename(coluName) from #t for xml path(''), type ).value('.', 'nvarchar(max)') ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'select id, ' + @cols + '  
              from #t
              pivot ( max(amount) for coluName in (' + @cols + ') ) p '
select @query
execute sp_executesql @query;
```

So, the idea is to use a simple `PIVOT` on your table, pivoting the column `coluName`. The values you need to get dynamically each time, since you don't have a static list of `coluName` values.

You can check out a good explanation on dynamic pivoting [here](http://sqlhints.com/2014/03/18/dynamic-pivot-in-sql-server/).

You can check a working version of this query [here](http://rextester.com/HKNXPS39756).

> **EDIT**:

To answer your question in the comments, the same table #t could be used like this (specify your correct data types, I put `int`, `numeric` and `varchar` as an example):

```
if object_id('tempdb..#t') is not null drop table #t 
create table #t (id int, amount numeric, coluName varchar(10))

insert into #t
select e.id, e.Amount, i.ColuName
from FixAm e inner join InCo i on i.CCode = e.CCode
where i.cid = 49
```

Then simply use the above dynamic pivot.

Comment: you just put everything you need as source inside the @query when creating it as a string.

Comment: when i do this in @query .. select e.id,e.Amount,i.ColuName
 from FixAm  e
inner join InCo i on i.CCode=e.CCode
where cid=49 ... this shows an multiple error mostly errors are multi-part identifier could not be bound error...

Comment: `cid` is a field of which table?

Comment: Ok, specify it in your query in the `where` condition to avoid errors and just store all the result of this `join` in a `temporary table`. Use that `temporary table` as a source for the pivot as is done in the answer I provided above.
I updated the answer, you can take a look! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
IF Object_id('tempdb..#tempTab') IS NOT NULL
Drop table #tempTab

;WITH Cte(id,Amount,coluName    )
AS
(
Select 13,25000,'abccol' UNION ALL  
Select 13,2300, 'defcol'  
)
SELECT * INTO #tempTab FROM cte 

Declare @Columns nvarchar(max), @Sql nvarchar(max)


SELECT @Columns=STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ', '+ QuoteName(coluName)  FROM #tempTab  
FOR XML PATH ('')),1,1,'') from #tempTab 
--SELECT @Columns

SET @Sql='SELECT [id],'+@Columns+'From
            (
            SELECT id,Amount,coluName
            from #tempTab
            )
            AS Src
                Pivot
                (
                MAX(Amount) For coluName  IN ('+@Columns +')
                )Pvt '
Print @Sql
EXecute (@Sql)
```

OutPut

```
id  abccol  defcol
-------------------
13  25000   2300
```